# Capistrano doesn't deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When I run

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

Capistrano starts doing tasks, but stops after checking tasks and exit.

Nevertheless, my releases folder on server is empty.
Here is my deploy.rb:

```
    # Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
    set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps1/#{fetch(:application)}"

    # Default value for :scm is :git
    # set :scm, :git

    # Default value for :format is :pretty
    # set :format, :pretty

    # Default value for :log_level is :debug
    # set :log_level, :debug

    # Default value for :pty is false
    # set :pty, true

    # Default value for :linked_files is []
    set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

    # Default value for linked_dirs is []
    set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

    # Default value for default_env is {}
    # set :default_env, { path2: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

    # Default value for keep_releases is 5
    set :keep_releases, 5

    namespace :deploy do
      %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
        desc "#{command} unicorn server"
        task command do
          on roles :app do
            execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)} #{command}"
          end
        end
      end
      task :setup_config do
        on roles :app do
          sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:application)}"
          sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}"
          execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
          execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/socket"
        end
      end
      # after 'deploy:setup', 'deploy:setup_config'

      # task :symlink_config do
      #   on roles :app do
      #     execute "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
      #   end
      # end
      # after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:symlink_config'

      desc 'Make sure local git is in sync with remote.'
      task :check_revision do
        on roles :web do
          unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
            puts 'WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master'
            puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
            exit
          end
        end
      end
      before 'deploy', 'deploy:check_revision'

    end
```

Here is my console log(my_ip is server ip, my_user is my server username, my_local_user is my local username):

```
    rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
    ruby-2.3.0
    ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
    00:00 git:wrapper
          01 mkdir -p /tmp
        ✔ 01 my_user@my_ip 0.027s
          Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-my_app-production-my_local_user.sh 100.0%
          02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-my_app-production-my_local_user.sh
        ✔ 02 my_user@my_ip 0.036s
    00:00 git:check
          01 git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:my_app/my_app.git
          01 b440ec9ce098e4cfb733a39f2f65c898ce579583   refs/heads/master
        ✔ 01 my_user@my_ip 2.748s
    00:02 deploy:check:directories
          01 mkdir -p /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/releases
        ✔ 01 my_user@my_ip 0.015s
    00:02 deploy:check:linked_dirs
          01 mkdir -p /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/log /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/tmp/pids /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/tmp/cache /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/tmp/so…
        ✔ 01 my_user@my_ip 0.014s
    00:02 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
          01 mkdir -p /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/config
        ✔ 01 my_user@my_ip 0.012s
    00:03 deploy:check:linked_files
          linked file /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on my_ip
```

If I delete deploy directory or current release, or change deploy directory, logs are same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `linked file /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on my_ip` This seems to be the reason (if that is indeed the last line in the log). Make sure the database.yml file is present at the location cap is expecting.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, I fixed this, then it was similar message with secrets.yml. I scp'ed this file and that worked! Thank you! There wasn't any errors in logs, so i decided, that Capistrano just didn't do some tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the answer from the comment above:

`linked file /home/my_user/apps1/my_app/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on my_ip` This seems to be the reason (if that is indeed the last line in the log). Make sure the `database.yml` file is present at the location cap is expecting.